# как выпилить (updated_at) laravel

Tags: php, laravel

почему приходить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя у меня в миграции прописаны

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('history_passwords', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->date('created_at');
        $table->index('user_id','history_password_user_idx');
        $table->foreign('user_id','history_password_user_fk')->
        on('users')->references('id');
    });
}
```

> Код который прописан в контроллере

```
 HistoryPassword::create([
  'user_id' => $user->id,
  'password' =>  $user->password,
  'description' => 'change'
]);
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду :?
мол ошибку ручками надо написать ?

Comment: В  `HistoryPassword` переопределите свойство `public $timestamps = false;`